# TikZ nodepart enumeration

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes

When I enumerate nodes I can write for example:

```
\nodepart{sixteen}1
```

But I need to make nodes with numbers: twenty-one or more. How can I do that?
When I write

```
\nodepart{twenty-one}1
```

Latex returns an error.

I was trying to find any example, but I didn't found anything what is more than twenty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tikz/pgf manual says:

> **Shape rectangle split:** 
>   This shape is a rectangle which can be either split horizontally or vertically into several parts... The shape can be split into a maximum of **twenty** parts. However, to avoid allocating a lot of unnecessary boxes, pgf only allocates four boxes by default.

I think you would be better off by using chains, which in my experience more flexible.